# Derivative of $\frac { y }{ x } +\frac { x }{ y } =2y$ with respect to $x$

Tags: calculus

$$\frac { y }{ x } +\frac { x }{ y } =2y$$

Steps I took:

$$\frac { d }{ dx } \left[yx^{ -1 }1+xy^{ -1 }\right]=\frac { d }{ dx } [2y]$$

$$\frac { dy }{ dx } \left(\frac { 1 }{ x } \right)+(y)\left(-\frac { 1 }{ x^{ 2 } } \right)+(1)\left(\frac { 1 }{ y } \right)+(x)\left(-\frac { 1 }{ y^{ 2 } } \right)\frac { dy }{ dx } =(2)\frac { dy }{ dx } $$

$$-\frac { y }{ x^{ 2 } } +\frac { 1 }{ y } =(2)\frac { dy }{ dx } -\left(\frac { 1 }{ x } \right)\frac { dy }{ dx } +\left(\frac { x }{ y^{ 2 } } \right)\frac { dy }{ dx } $$

$$-\frac { y }{ x^{ 2 } } +\frac { 1 }{ y } =\left(2-\frac { 1 }{ x } +\frac { x }{ y^{ 2 } } \right)\frac { dy }{ dx } $$

$$\frac { -\frac { y }{ x^{ 2 } } +\frac { 1 }{ y }  }{ \left(2-\frac { 1 }{ x } +\frac { x }{ y^{ 2 } } \right) } =\frac { dy }{ dx } $$

At this point I get stuck because once I simplify the result of the last step I took, the answer is not what it should be. I think that I am making a careless mistake somewhere but I cannot seem to find it. Hints only, please. The direct answer does nothing for me.

Actual answer:

$$\frac { d y}{ dx } =\frac { y(y^{ 2 }-x^{ 2 }) }{ x(y^{ 2 }-x^{ 2 }-2xy^{ 2 }) } $$

Comment: I think you mean $\frac{d}{dx}(yx^{-1}+xy^{-1})=\frac{d}{dx}(2y)$

Comment: I think you mean $\frac{d}{dx}[yx^{-1}]$, not $\frac{dy}{dx}[yx^{-1}]$

Comment: In these sorts of problems, I find it easier to multiply both sides of the equation by $xy$, and then putting a note on the side to remember that $xy \ne 0$.

Comment: Alternatively, after multiplying by $y$, you can solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ using the quadratic formula. But I suspect that is not the sort of answer wanted. BTW, if you know what the answer "should be," why not tell the people trying to help you?

Comment: Another approach: Let $v=\frac{y}{x}$ and then first differentiate $v+v^{-1} = 2xv$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: That "actual answer" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry about the poor notation and accidentally making a mistake when putting up the actual answer. It seems that my last step was correct despite those errors. I just needed to follow through as randomgirl demonstrated below

Comment: @ThomasAndrews

How does the denominator of the "actual answer" simplify to that from what I would have ended up with if I just followed through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text{ Assuming your y' is correct... } \\ \text{  then we should get rid of the compound fractions.. } \\ y'=\frac{\frac{-y}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y}}{2-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{x}{y^2}} \\  \text{ now we need to multiply top and bottom by } \\ x^2y^2 \text{ this is the lcm of the bottoms of the mini-fractions } \\ y'=\frac{-y(y^2)+1(x^2)(y)}{2x^2y^2-xy^2+x(x^2)} \\ y'=\frac{-y^3+x^2y}{2x^2y^2-xy^2+x^3}$

Comment: So it seems that my last step was heading in the right direction. I just needed to follow through with the steps you took and would have arrived at the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

it will be a whole lot easier to turn $$  \frac { y }{ x } +\frac { x }{ y } =2y$$ into $$ x^2 + y^2 = 2xy^2$$ and difference as $$2x\,dx + 2y\, dy = 4xy \, dy +2y^2 \, dx $$ which can then be simplifies as $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y^2 - x}{y(1-2x)}\, \text{ and subject to the onstraint  }  \frac { y }{ x } +\frac { x }{ y } =2y.$$